# What happens to service client when service server crashes?

Tags: ros, service, rosservice, ros-service, call-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I create a service server node and then, for whatever reason, the node crashes, what happens to all of the clients which were connected to the server?

If the server node respawns at some point, can the clients continue to use the service server automatically?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193812/what-happens-to-service-client-when-service-server-crashes?/) by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the service client is non-persistent (the default), the node implementing the server can change (eg. creash, respawn), and clients will properly reconnect when the next request is made. If the client is persistent, then you need to negotiate reconnections yourself.

More info for roscpp and rospy, respectively, can be found here:

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Services#Persistent_Connections

http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Services#Persistent_connections

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-09-30**:
You mean "persistent", not "non-persistent" in the second statement, right?

**Comment by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) on 2014-09-30**:
I believe he does

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-09-30**:
Thanks for catching the typo. Fixed now.